# How can we parse a JSON file for specific records of county borders and overlay that on a Folium HeatMap?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, folium

I found a JSON file that has borders of US counties, right here.

https://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json

How can I parse that file for specific records, like 'Durham' and 'Raleigh' and 'Charlotte' together, and plot these on a Folium map? When I run the code below, I have all counties plotted on the map, be because no specific counties are parsed out before mapping.

```
from folium import GeoJson
geo=r"C:\\Users\\RShuell\\Downloads\\gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json"

file = open(geo)
text = file.read()
m = folium.Map(width="%100",weight="%100")
GeoJson(text).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

Finally, how would I overlap a HeatMap on top of the plotted county borders? When I create a Folium HeatMap, it overwrites all the county borders!

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap


max_amount = float(df_2std['Total_Cust_Minutes'].max())

hmap = folium.Map(location=[35.5, -82.5], zoom_start=7, )


hm_wide = HeatMap(list(zip(df_2std.Circuit_Latitude.values, 
                           df_2std.Circuit_Longitude.values, 
                           df_2std.Total_Cust_Minutes.values)),
                   min_opacity=0.2,
                   max_val=max_amount,
                   radius=25, 
                   blur=20, 
                   max_zoom=1, 
                 )

hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the file?  The "features" element is a list of individual shapes.  The shapes have a state number, a county number, and a county name.  You would have to know which state number you need, but it's easy to filter that data based on the state number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.  I don't know if their GeoJSON can handle objects or if has to be text, so this code (a) reads in the JSON and converts to an object, (b) filters the objects to keep those in state 037 (which, I think, is North Carolina), then (c) converts that back to a JSON string.

```
import json
from folium import GeoJson

data = json.load(open('gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json'))
newdata = { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [] }

for row in data['features']:
    if row['properties']["STATE"] == '37':
        newdata['features'].append( row )

text = json.dumps(newdata)

m = folium.Map(width="%100",weight="%100")
GeoJson(text).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I tried pointing to the gz file that I downloaded and got this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
There has got to be a way to read directly from the http source...I think...

Comment: My mistake, json.load expects a file handle, not a file name.  I always get tripped up by that, because I would not have designed it that way.  Of course you can fetch the file directly, using the `requests` module.  Since the file doesn't change, I'm not sure that's the best plan.

Comment: Thanks again! The code runs, and does not throw an error, but nothing gets displayed in my Jupyter Notebook. Does it actually work for you?

Comment: The state code is is 37, not 037.  I didn't try it, because I don't have folium, but if you fix the state code, the JSON looks right.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it works!! It's very amazing how you, myself, and others can do all kinds of things with technology. Thanks a ton!!!